# What are the organisms that are used for toxicology studies in water?

Tags: water, toxicity

I have heard that zebra fish is used for toxicology studies . Is there any other organism that is actively used for toxicological studies?https://www.google.co.in/search?q=zebrafish+toxicity+studies&oq=zebra+fish+tox&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.11109j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Not sure if on topic here... feels rather Biology to me.

Comment: Definitely more of a biology question. Also, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquatic_toxicology

Comment: @orthocresol.I am sorry if it's off topic . But there are many projects going on in the branch of environmental engineering to determine toxicity of effluents(domestic and industrial)with these organisms. So i was curious to know about other organisms that are involved in this study like zebra fish

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the selection of  appropriate organisms for "toxicology-studies" is by and large, a biologist's problem. Burn this question with fire! On a more serious note, this ought to be migrated to the Bio.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Well, sometimes daphnia (*Daphnia Magna* also known as water fleas) are used in toxicology bioassays a an indicator genus. I have  personally experimented with Daphnia before, and it is easy to see their internal organs through their transparent body. For example, [this study](http://lib.gig.ac.cn/local/ejournal/ETC/ETC2006/2504/ETC-2006-25(4)-1132-1137.pdf) uses Daphnia to test the effect of nanoparticles on Daphnia and [this article](http://www.nrcresearchpress.com/doi/abs/10.1139/f72-269#.WVj7-Yjys2w) shows the effects of heavy metals on Daphnia. For more information, visit [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphnia#Uses).